# Enumerate through an array returned by asp.net core web api in javascript

Tags: javascript

My asp.net core Web API returns Id and Names like this:

```
[HttpGet("{id}/names")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<VisaNameDto>> GetVisaNames(string id)
{
   visaNames = await visaDtoRepo.GetVisaNames(id);
   return visaNames;
}

public class VisaNameDto
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I consume this API and console log on the client I get the output as:

```
const uri = "https://localhost:44395/visa/ae/names";
fetch(uri)
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((data) => console.log(data));
------------------------------------------------------------
{$id: '1', $values: Array(7)}
$id: "1"
$values: Array(7)
0: {$id: '2', id: 1, name: '48 Hours Transit Visa'}
1: {$id: '3', id: 2, name: '30 Days Tourist Visa'}
2: {$id: '4', id: 3, name: '30 Days Multiple Entry Tourist Visa '}
3: {$id: '5', id: 4, name: '96 Hours Transit Visa'}
4: {$id: '6', id: 5, name: '14 Days Tourist Visa '}
5: {$id: '7', id: 6, name: '14 Days Tourist Visa (Express)'}
6: {$id: '8', id: 7, name: '30 Days Tourist Visa (Express)'}
length: 7
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

How can I loop through this in JavaScript and access the Id and Name? I am not even getting the length of this (data.length shows undefined). Also where does the $id comes from?

Comment: try pasting the JSON response so we can we see what it looks like, what you have there does not seem to be valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is an object with properties `$id` and `$values`.

```
const uri = "https://localhost:44395/visa/ae/names";
fetch(uri)
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then(data => {
      data.$values.forEach(value => {
         // do something with value, eg.
         console.log(value.$id, value.id, value.name)
      })
   });
```

Comment: It works. Thanks! Is this the way asp.net core outputs IEnumerable as JSON (with $value and $id)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ASP.NET so not sure what control you have over the response format.  As long as its consistent and you understand how to work with it, that should suffice.